# How to replace a character with another without using replace()

Tags: java

I am not allowed to use replace().  All I can use are substring and indexOf and length().  How can I replace characters using those methods?  This is what I've tried, but it doesn't work.

```
public static String replace(String s)
{
  int b = 0;
  String result = "";
  int index = s.indexOf(' ');

  while(index != -1)
  {
     result += s.substring(b,index) + '\n';
     s = s.substring(index+1);
     index = s.indexOf(' ');
  }

  return result;
}
```

***Correction:  I took out the `b = index;` because I realized that was a mistake.  Now it works with the only problem that the LAST CHARACTER of the string does not show up because the part `str.indexOf(' '); is -1 which does not meet the conditions of the loop.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Replace `' '` with `'\n'`?

Comment: Yes.  A space with a new line character

Comment: And is this some kind of odd homework assignment? What's the purpose? What are you meant to be learning from it?

Comment: A simpler solution could be to loop over the string and have a test on each character whether it is a blank.  If so, append a newline character to the result string, otherwise the character itself.

Comment: its from AP Com Sci.  That's why I cant use any other method

Comment: return result+s in your current code should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the previous `index` in `b`. Also, you can use the second argument to `indexOf()` to control your position in the `String`. Like,

```
public static String replace(String s) {
    int b = 0;
    String result = "";
    int index = s.indexOf(' ');
    if (index > -1) {
        while (index != -1) {
            result += s.substring(b, index) + '\n';
            // s = s.substring(index + 1);
            b = index;
            index = s.indexOf(' ', index + 1);
        }
        result += s.substring(b + 1);
    } else {
        result = s;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without indexOf and substring.
 The implementation is taken from java.lang.String.replace().

```
public static String replace(String str, char oldChar, char newChar) {
    if (oldChar != newChar) {
        char[] value = str.toCharArray();
        int len = value.length;
        int i = -1;
        char[] val = value;

        while (++i < len) {
            if (val[i] == oldChar) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i < len) {
            char buf[] = new char[len];
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                buf[j] = val[j];
            }
            while (i < len) {
                char c = val[i];
                buf[i] = (c == oldChar) ? newChar : c;
                i++;
            }
            return new String(buf);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, unless you MUST use all the methods you mentioned. Regardless, may be food for thought.

```
  public static String replace(String s) {
    String[] split = s.split("");
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
      if (split[i].equals(" ")) {
        split[i] = "\n";
      }
      result+=split[i];
    }


    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve that task by using a recursive method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(replace("a b c ..."));
}

public static String replace(final String str) {
    final int index = str.indexOf(' '); // find the first occurence
    if (index == - 1) { // if there are no whitespaces ...
        return str; // ... then return the unchanged String
    }
    // cut off the part before the whitespace, append \n to it and then append
    // the result of another "replace" call with the part after the found whitespace
    return String.format("%s%s%s",
        str.substring(0, index), "\n", replace(str.substring(index + 1)));
}
```

The comments in the code should describe the behavior of the recursive method. If you have a question about it, the leave a comment.